# What test to run to analyse my data

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova, multiple-comparisons, independence

I am new to stats and unsure what test to use to analyze my data.

[image]
I am wanting to find out if the number of individuals in each category is significantly different. There are 11 categories A-K.
It is not independent as sightings could be the same individuals over time.

I am using r and have tried to do an anova using lmer followed by pairwise Bonferroni, which works but I don't think is right with the columns I have (what to use as the random variable ( +(1|.?.))and while it works the pairwise results are also not what I would expect.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you give some background? How do "Water clarity" codes 1,2, etc. differ from "Water clarity category"? Describe "Nr of Individuals" (who did what?). What linkage did you expect btw Category and Individuals? [What are the five and a half Fs for?]